# Firebase return null value

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is the structure:

[image]

I wanna select the company, phone and city where the email = current email of the connected user.

This is my code:

```
DatabaseReference mDatabases = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

Query query = mDatabases.child("Users").orderByChild("email").equalTo(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getEmail().toString());

query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {


            User user =  dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            String company = user.getCompany();
            String city = user.getCity);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

The returned result is null.

When i change `dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)` to `dataSnapshot.getValue()`, it return all values of the node.

Comment: Log not show any erros? Connections error or something? Your object User are with all getters and setters ? Try .getEmail() before in a variable after get value then user in comparation.

Comment: You've included a link to a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't indicated which user you want to retrieve. As your dataSnapshot returns a list of user values (even the list has only 1 element), you have to specify which user you want to get:

```
User user =  dataSnapshot.child(userId).getValue(User.class);
```

Replace `userId` to the id of the user you want to retrieve (current user I guess!)

Comment: If possible, please provide me your `dataSnapshot.getValue()` 's return values!